# String.valueOf((String)jsonBodyMap.get(pfield))) is retuning null from the JSON object

Tags: apex, json, apexrest

Hi im trying to fetch the string value from JSOn object dynamically and its retuning null, works fine if i specify the field names but i dont want to hardcode the field names want to pass it pass it dynamically. any suggestions? here is sample code(Line 27 to 29).

```
public PageReference  JSON_ResponseHandler() {        
       String jsonbody ='{"state":"WA","retirementAge":"65","age":"51","firstName":"ku","lastName":"su","dateOfBirth":"01/07/1964"}';
        Map<String,String> FieldMap=util.getFieldMap();
        Map<String,String> FieldTypeMap=util.getFieldTypeMap();
        string qFields=String.join(FieldMap.values(), ', ');
        string uNum='';
        String pName;
        Map<String, Object> jsonBodyMap = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonbody);

        if(!string.IsBlank((String)jsonBodyMap.get('userNum'))){
            uNum = !string.IsBlank((String)jsonBodyMap.get('userNum'))?String.valueOf((String)jsonBodyMap.get('userNum')):'';
        }

        string query ='SELECT ' + qFields
                       + ' FROM contact'
                       + ' WHERE user_num__c = \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(uNum) + '\''
                       + ' LIMIT 1';
        system.debug(LoggingLevel.error,'query#'+query);

        p=Database.query(query);

        for(String pfield:FieldMap.keySet()){
            string s= string.valueOf((String)jsonBodyMapLcase.get(pfield));
            system.debug(LoggingLevel.error,'sXX=' + s);

            if('Text'==FieldTypeMap.get(pfield)){
                system.debug(LoggingLevel.error,'field Value from Jsonbody:'+String.valueOf((String)jsonBodyMap.get(pfield)));
                // retuns allways NULL, if i specify the field name then its retunring the value. its not working if we pass it dynamically
                p.put(FieldMap.get(pfield),String.valueOf((String)jsonBodyMap.get(pfield)));
            }
        }
        system.debug(LoggingLevel.error,'updated Participant=' + p);
        update p;
        return new PageReference('/'+p.id);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the map returned by `JSON.deserializeUntyped` the key values are case sensitive. So "firstName" would work but "FirstName" or "firstname" would not. The values in your `FieldMap` presumably do not match the casing in your JSON.

Writing a case-insensitive wrapper for the map would be one way to work-around the problem. Or fix a casing convention that is easy to use everywhere e.g. always lower case.

A wrapper might look like this:

```
public class CaseInsensitiveLookup {

    private Map<String, Object> m;
    private Map<String, String> keys = new Map<String, String>();

    public CaseInsensitiveLookup(Map<String, Object> m) {
        this.m = m;
        this.keys = new Map<String, String>();
        for (String key : m.keySet()) {
           keys.put(key.toLowerCase(), key);
        }
    }

    public Object get(String caseInsensitiveKey) {
        return m.get(keys.get(caseInsensitiveKey.toLowerCase()));
    }
}

Map<String, Object> jsonBodyMap = ...
CaseInsensitiveLookup lookup = new CaseInsensitiveLookup(jsonBodyMap);
...
    p.put(FieldMap.get(pfield), (String) lookup.get(pfield));
```

Comment: im aware of the casesensitivity issue, i do have another map to converted them all to lowercase and also read them all to lowercase. i just removed that code while posting ..to make it more simple.

Comment: @KrForce OK. Then I suggest you add `System.debug` calls to see what exactly is the difference between your working hard-coded keys and the dynamic non-working keys.

Comment: @Keith..just an update...its related to casesensitivity only...there was another map for field and its Data type. that also needs to be converted into lowercase...which i missed. Thanks for your response.